# How to select all records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a gridview filled with data, it only fills with data for signed in User by calling this SP.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Employee].[usp_getAllEmployeesReliefs]

    @EmployeeID INT

AS
BEGIN

    SELECT EmployeeReliefID,
           Amount,
           [Employee].[Relief].IsActive,
           PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoName,
           [Setup].Reliefs.Name AS ReliefName
    FROM [Employee].[Relief]
    INNER JOIN PersonalInfo ON PersonalInfo.pk_PersonalInfo_ID = Employee_ID
    INNER JOIN [Setup].Reliefs ON [Setup].Reliefs.ReliefID = [Employee].[Relief].Relief_ID
    WHERE employeeID = @EmployeeID
    ORDER BY EmployeeReliefID DESC

END
```

But I want to show records that are assinged to employee and also that are not assigned to employee. How to do that ?

Comment: remove the where clause?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  For instance, hat does "assigned to"  mean in the context of your tables?

Comment: Am sure you are looking for this `..WHere employeeID= @EmployeeID or @EmployeeID  IS NULL`

Comment: you may need to use left-join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can something like this:
- Change the parameter to have a default value
- change your where clause to `(employeeID = @EmployeeID OR @EmployeeID IS NULL)`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Employee].[usp_getAllEmployeesReliefs]
    @EmployeeID INT = NULL -- default value to make the parameter optional
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT EmployeeReliefID,
           Amount,
           [Employee].[Relief].IsActive,
           PersonalInfo.PersonalInfoName,
           [Setup].Reliefs.Name AS ReliefName
    FROM [Employee].[Relief]
    INNER JOIN PersonalInfo ON PersonalInfo.pk_PersonalInfo_ID = Employee_ID
    INNER JOIN [Setup].Reliefs ON [Setup].Reliefs.ReliefID = [Employee].[Relief].Relief_ID
    WHERE (employeeID = @EmployeeID OR @EmployeeID IS NULL)
    ORDER BY EmployeeReliefID DESC

END
```

This way, you can call your procedure with or without parameter.

```
EXEC usp_getAllEmployeesReliefs --get all records
EXEC usp_getAllEmployeesReliefs 111 --get record with ID 111
```